# Is there a way in angular to update the rowData when value changes inside a cellRendererComponent, when using ag-grid-angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I have a column definition as following:

```
    colDef = [{
       headerName: 'Cell ID',
       field: 'cellId',
       cellRendererFramework: CellIdCellRendererComponent,
    },
    {
       headerName: 'Set ID',
       field: 'cellId'
       cellRendererFramework: SetIdCellRendererComponent,
    }]
```

Within the cellIdCellRendererComponent, I'm trying to update the entire RowData as below:

```
this.params.api.updateRowData(this.params.data);
```

Comment: You are trying to update same cell value or another?

Comment: I'm trying to update another cell value, in the first cell I have a dropdown, and based on the selection of value in dropdown, I have to update the values of dropdown in next column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to update another cell value, in the first cell I have a
>   dropdown, and based on the selection of value in dropdown, I have to
>   update the values of dropdown in next column.

So you just need to use [`setDataValue`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#updating-rownodes-data) method

```
params.node.setDataValue(anotherCell, anotherCellNewValue):
```

Comment: This worked for me. thanks a lot for the answer @un.spike

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using `node` property of your `ICellRendererParams`.

```
this.params.node.updateData(this.params.data);
```

Check the definition.

```
export interface ICellRendererParams {
   ...
   node: RowNode;
}
```

`updateData(data: any): void;` is a method or `RowNode`.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, node.updateData works for the first time when I change something inside that cellRendererComponent, again when I tried to make some changes in the same cell, the agInit of second cell is not getting called.

Comment: What makes u think agInit should get called when the value is updated? I think it's called only once while the renderer is initialized.

Comment: I wanted to update the values of cellId cell component based on the selection in setId , so I wanted the agInit of cellId to be executed when I modify the value of setId.
Question is updated to clarify this comment.